# Post from xamarin to restful API

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.android

I am trying to make an API call from xamarin, this is my first Full mobile app calling restful API (.NetCore3.1) with a Angular WebApp.
All other API calls from the xamarin app are working,
The issue is I need to send a File with an object, file can be .doc .png etc.

GrantApplication.cs
API Endpoint

```
    public class FileProvider
    {
        public string GA { get; set; }
        public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
    }


         [HttpPost]
        [Route("[action]")]
        public ActionResult SubmitGrantApplication([FromForm] FileProvider fileProvider)
        {
            try
            {
                var ga = fileProvider;
                byte[] fileContent = null;
                var files = Request.Form.Files.Any() ? Request.Form.Files : new FormFileCollection();
                var grant = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GrantApplication>(ga.GA);
               ...
            }
        }
```

GrantService.cs
Call made from the mobile app:
This call is returning a 400 response with no clear indication why.
I am trying to figure out why, And my postman skills aren't that great to convert the code to postman.

The error returned at #5.

::"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
public class GrantService
    {
        public static async Task<GrantApplication> SubmitGrant(GrantApplication ga,string file, string FileName, StreamContent FileData)
        {
                Uri requestUri = new Uri($"{ApiSettings.ApiBaseUrl}/grantapplication/SubmitGrantApplication");
                try
                {
                    var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                    //using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    //{
                    //    //MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    //    //ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
                    //    //StringContent GA = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ga));
                    //    //content.Add(baContent, "Files", FileName);
                    //    //content.Add(GA, "GA");
                    //    //Console.WriteLine(content);
                    //    //var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
                    //    //Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    //    //return ga;
                    //}
                    using (var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
                        // 3. Add the filename C:\\... + fileName is the path your file
                        Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file);
                        formContent.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), FileName, FileName);
                        var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ga);
                        HttpContent content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        formContent.Add(content, "GA");
                        using (var client = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            // Bearer Token header if needed
                            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));

                            try
                            {
                                // 4.. Execute the MultipartPostMethod
                                var message = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, formContent);
                                // 5.a Receive the response
                                var result = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                Console.WriteLine(result);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Do what you want if it fails.
                                throw ex;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return ga;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    return ga;
                }
           
        }
    }
```

Web System
Angular API call

```
public SubmitGrantApplication(grantApplication){
    grantApplication.memberId = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedInUser")).memberID;
    grantApplication.ClientID = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("LoggedInUser")).clientID;
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type' :  'multipart/form-data' });
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept':  'multipart/form-data'});
    let myFormData: FormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append("Files", grantApplication.documentContent);
    myFormData.append("GA", JSON.stringify(grantApplication));
    return this.http.post<GrantApplication>(this.url+"SubmitGrantApplication", myFormData , { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

Swagger

[Swagger Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLtPY.png)

Works
[Angular API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txQRu.png)
Works
[Payload Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUfbT.png)

Comment: Just a friendly advice; when working with APIs, you may want to test your end-points with Postman first, especially when you run into trouble. BR

Comment: In angular the end point works perfectly fine,
Is there a way I can point my Visual Studio xamarin project to localhost port where I run my debug version then? Note I am only experiencing issue from xamarin side trying to post multipart the IFormFile part is the snag here I think

Comment: Note this is my first app and web app I am writing to use one .netcore restfull service

Comment: You should update your question with info that this is working with Angular. And let's wait for a Xamarin-person to solve this. BR

Comment: @JohnathanFourie Where do you get 400 error in GrantService.cs? From your error message, it seems that you need on instance of an object.

Comment: Yeah Grantservice.sc in the response of the post async

Comment: @JohnathanFourie Just having problem when call restful API in Xamarin? Do you try to call restful API in other project, for example console app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post works perfectly, there was an issue present within the mail function to attach the file received by the API, the file properties are differently set and it failed to attach the file from bytearray...
Fixed the call and added a throw exception within the API,
Never return BadRequest(); in the catch section. error 400 will throw and not the standard error 500 server error

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your case and with same code (unused code was removed)

It works, can you share whole response of PostAsync? url, response code and other properties can tell us something

```
    public static async Task<dynamic> SubmitGrant(object ga, string file, string FileName)
    {
        var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Uri requestUri = new Uri($"https://localhost:44341/grantapplication/SubmitGrantApplication");
            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
            StringContent GA = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ga));
            content.Add(baContent, "Files", FileName);
            content.Add(baContent, "Files", 1 + FileName); /* test 2 files */
            content.Add(GA, "GA");
            Console.WriteLine(content);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            return ga;
        }
    }
```

Calling Method

```
await SubmitGrant(new { Test = 123 }, "C:\\Temp\\MyPicture.jpg", "MyPicture.jpg");
```

Receiving Data and Files

[image]

Comment: Tried the code and I am getting a 400 response,
Somewhere my payload or headers are giving me an issue.

I am trying to replicate my angular call to my API endpoint exactly if possible